# Button image is not displayed with FlatStyle.System

Tags: vb.net

I am new to Visual Basic.NET, and programming.
I have a Form with 4 buttons, the same image has been assigned to these buttons.
With Flatstyle.Flat, Flatstyle.Standard and Flatstyle.Popup the image is displayed correctly.
 With Flatstyle.System the image is not displayed.
I am trying to find a way around this problem. For this I tried 2 solutions:

1. I drew an image (img1) but I don't know how to put it in the foreground so that it is above the control button.

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    Dim img1 As Image = My.Resources.image
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    g.DrawImage(img1, New Rectangle(260, 180, 24, 24))
End Sub
```

2. I have drawn the icon (img2) in the button (System) but I don't know how to display it when I open the program, for the moment it appears when I click on button3 (Popup) and disappears when I hover over the button it is drawn on (Button4, System).

```
Private Sub Popup_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim img2 As Image = My.Resources.image
    Dim g As Graphics = Button4.CreateGraphics()
    g.DrawImage(img2, 9, 13, 24, 24)
End Sub
```

Have a look at the picture attached : [Form1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlRjV.jpg)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to draw on a `Button`, handle the `Paint` event of that `Button`, not of the form. NEVER call `CreateGarphics`.

Also, don't access the same property of `My.Resources` over and over again. It will extract a new object from resources every time. Access the property once and assign the value to a field, then use that field repeatedly.

Comment: The easiest way was to add a label to the button and assign it a background image instead of complicating things. Thanks for your help.